# How to bend two parts of a flat objects on two different axis?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects, bezier-curves

[image]Hi guys, I already posted this on reddit blenderhelp but I think it kinda became a meme, and even though I fixed a few things my problem hasn't been solved.

I tried the bend tool and simple bend modifier with no success because it didn't give me enough control on the bend trajectory, I then tried the bezier curve modifier, I applied a bend on the X Axis, to have the wrist part curve, then a second bend on the Z axis to have the top part curve down too.

My problem is that I want the top part to be flat on the X Axis, because after a 180° Z Bend, the top part of the object now moves away from the X Bend trajectory, as it is now mirrored.

I tried applying Vertex groups on the bottom half so that the top wouldn't bend on the X Axis, but blender doesn't make a smooth transition between flat and bent parts, I get weird connection polys instead of a fluid twist (or untwist in this case).

Is there any simple way to bend an object in two different directions ? A bit like so https://blenderartists.org/t/c4d-like-bend-deformer/1146668

Comment: Completely rewritten the answer to address the need for the end of the fold to be flat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could go with the Bend, using limits and Axis/Orientation Empties in the modifiers, but IMO, you would get finer control over the curves using Curve modifiers throughout?

**Excluding the flat region from the circular curve modifier**

In order to keep the end of the folded-over region flat, it must remain unaffected ***either*** by the mapping of the entire object into the curve, ***or*** the subsequent deformation. The first is achieved by arranging origins.

- The circle's origin is placed at its first vertex, and at World 0.
- The object's origin is placed at the center of its X dimension, at its minimum Z
- The object is then translated in X (effectively rotating it around the circle under deformation) until the part of the mesh we want to remain stationary is directly above the circle's origin.

[image]

The second is achieved by weight painting:

- The circle Curve modifier (deforming in X) is aimed at a vertex group - it does not affect the unweighted region:

[image]

The bottom is curved, the top remains flat, ***and*** in place.

**Adding a second curve modifier to fold over a section.**

The folding curve modifier deforms in Z, its curve can be anywhere you like in X, but here shown with its origin in the same place as the circle curve.

[image]

You could flatten more or less of the flap with weight-painting.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi and thanks for the input Robin. Well that's what I did, I used Bezier Curve modifier, but as I said, I'd like the top part to stay flat while the bottom curves around the wrist and have a clean horizontal bend for the top part.The bend tool didn't give me enough flexibility, I will have a look at the Axis/Orientation Empties in the modifiers.

Comment: I just wish I could have it bend around two cylinders, one placed vertically for the wrist curve, one placed horizontally, perpendicular to the first one, for the second bend. May be I need a CAD for this. I tried with Fusion 360, with no luck, there is no bend tool on this software ! While Autodesk has it in Inventor...

Comment: @NeanderMat see edit... Is this what you mean? This is just eyeballed. weight painting and adjusting the curve. It could be made into a perfect cylinder if that's what you need

Comment: Or.. you could even shrinkwrap to your 2 cylinders... depends.. if you need animated deformation..

Comment: Hey Robin, thanks for the edit, the weight painting seems like it would do the trick perfectly ! This is what I was missing when I tried applying vertex group modifiers. The transition between the bent part to the flat one was totally messed up and not smooth at all. I am not 100% confident in my understanding of the first method you proposed though, I will give it a try and adjust placement of every different element.

Comment: Yeah I've had a go with shrinkwrapping around cylinders already actually, but it wouldn't give me much maneuverability. At least at my current level with blender... Actually I would rather need a "bend around x shape to x degrees" tool, so that I could make a small cylinder on top, have my object wrap around it on 180° before going back down !

Comment: If you want a perfect circular arc in the fold, you could construct the second deformation curve _from_  a circle, extruding its inside end vertically.

Comment: Yeah I was just editing my last comment saying that I could actually do just that with curves hah. Anyway thank you very much for your help, it's late here so I will try the weight paint tomorrow and replicate your first method as well before reporting back, I need to fully understand this tool now before moving on with a peaceful mind !